# Удаление сразу нескольких файлов (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, файлы

Для удаления файлов использую

```
https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra
```

Конструкция

```
fs.remove(path.join(__dirname, '../../../static/small/' + req.body.image), function(err) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    callback(null);
});
```

Все удаляет, все хорошо, но мне нужно удалить файлы из нескольких директорий. Код выше удаляет файл из директории /small/, а нужно этот же файл удалить и из директорий /thumb/, /mid/, /full/

Возможно ли как то массивом указать файлы на удаление или же есть какие то другие способы уделить пачку файлов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для удобства возьмем библиотеку [async](https://github.com/caolan/async):

```
async.each(arrayWithFileNames, fs.remove, cb)
```

Все, профит)))

Answer (score 0):

С async, да можно пробежать циклом, я пока сидел кумекал, тоже цикл написал, только без async.

Может кому то и пригодится

```
var folder = ['folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3'];
for(index in folder) {
    fs.remove('/path/' + folder[index] + '/' + req.body.image), function(err){
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        console.log('done');
    });
}
```

Comment: Ну тогда уже `folder.forEach(...` лучше использовать. И при такой реализации вы не сможете отследить момент, когда все файлы удалены

Comment: Да, я в курсе. Через async сделал уже =)

Answer (score 0):

С remove работать не будет, вот так правильнее:

```
var folder = ['folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3'];
    for(index in folder) {
       fs.unlink('/path/' + folder[index] + '/' + req.body.image);
   }
```